# How to use [SetUp] method to arrange for a unit test. How about parameters?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
public class CoffeeStrengthEstimator
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Estimates the strength of the coffee (how many beans to use) depending on the button pressed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buttonPressed"> The numeral position of the button pressed</param>
    /// <returns>An enum value indicating the estimated coffee strength</returns>
    public CoffeeStrength EstimateCoffeeStrength(int buttonPressed)
    {
        if (buttonPressed == 1)
        {
            return CoffeeStrength.Light;
        }
        else if (buttonPressed == 2)
        {
            return CoffeeStrength.Medium;
        }
        else if (buttonPressed == 3)
        {
            return CoffeeStrength.Strong;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException ("Invalid Button press, please try again");
        }
    }
}

public enum CoffeeStrength
{
    Light,
    Medium,
    Strong
}
```

===> Is it ok to write a unit test to test the above method; and create a new object of class CoffeeMaker and object of Coffee class with a method that takes only 2 parameters?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 5):

It's not really clear what you are asking, but I assume that you are asking how to go about testing the `CoffeeStrengthEstimator` (using NUnit, based on `Setup` in the title).

A `SetUp` method runs before each test method within a test class so is used to set up common code required for each method - this could be providing stubs/fakes/mocks for any dependencies that the *System Under Test* requires, as well as perhaps instantiating an instance of the *System Under Test.*

A Test method can be parameterized to receive different arguments.

Putting this together, a test class for `CoffeeStrengthEstimator` might look like the following

```
[TestFixture]
public class CoffeeStrengthEstimatorTests
{
    private CoffeeStrengthEstimator _estimator;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        // common Arrange
        _estimator = new CoffeeStrengthEstimator();
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase(1, CoffeeStrength.Light)]
    [TestCase(2, CoffeeStrength.Medium)]
    [TestCase(3, CoffeeStrength.Strong)]
    public void EstimateCoffeeStrength_Returns_Expected_CoffeeStrength_For_Button_Pressed_1_2_or_3(int buttonPressed,
        CoffeeStrength expectedCoffeeStrength)
    {
        // Act
        var coffeeStrength = _estimator.EstimateCoffeeStrength(buttonPressed);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCoffeeStrength, coffeeStrength);
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase(-1)]
    [TestCase(0)]
    [TestCase(4)]
    public void EstimateCoffeeStrength_Throws_ArgumentException_When_Button_Pressed_Not_1_2_or_3(int buttonPressed)
    {
        // Act and Assert
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => _estimator.EstimateCoffeeStrength(buttonPressed));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Russ. So you mean i do not need to create an object of CoffeeMaker class and object of Coffee class to test this method?

Comment: The *System Under Test* in this case is `CoffeeStrengthEstimator`, and based on the code that you have provided, it looks like it can be tested in isolation of `CoffeeMaker` and `Coffee`. You may also have unit tests for `CoffeeMaker` and `Coffee` too, and in each case, the *System Under Test (SUT)* will be `CoffeeMaker` and `Coffee`, respectively i.e. unit tests should be focused only on testing the SUT.

Comment: Another Question. Do i need to add some reference,? TestFixture could not be found or miising in the assembly reference. [SetUp] is a method and it's used like a 'type'. [Test] and [Testcase] could not be found or missing an assembly refernce.

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2013, so i need to install them in VS, do i install all of them or some particular.

Comment: Have a look at the nuget documentation for how to install packages - http://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Manager-Dialog

Comment: Thanks Russ! i just downloaded them in VS and hope Everything will be fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries and welcome to Stack Overflow. If it answers your question, you can always mark the answer as accepted ;)